# Powershell - Is there a way to use $_ for two different objects that are piped one after another

Tags: powershell

I am trying

```
foreach ($vc in $vclist) {
    Connect-Viserver $vc -Credentiol (get-Credentiol)
    $vms = Get-VM

    $vmsView = $vms | Get-View | Select-Object @{N = 'HWVersion'; E = { $_.Guest.HwVersion } }
}
```

`$_.Guest.HwVersion` belongs to array op of get-view

is there a method/way I can also get variable from `$vms` array for example I want `$vms[currentObject].guest.VmId`

I did not have much to try but i do not want to loop all vms and want it in just want line where I can `select-Object`'s from `$vms` array and `Get-View` array and return to `$vmsView`

Comment: You can add more calculated property expression to the `Select-Object` call if you want: `Select-Object @{N = 'HWVersion'; E = { $_.Guest.HwVersion } }, @{N='VMId';E={$_.Guest.VmId}}`

Comment: That was my first try
this is something I am doing
 $run = $vms | Get-view | Select-Object 
@{N='uuid';E={$_.guest.VmId.substring(15)+"@"+$vc}},
        name,PowerState,
        @{N='GuestHostname';E={$_.Guest.HostName}},
        @{N='ToolsStatus';E={$_.Guest.ToolsStatus}},
        @{N='ToolsVersionStatus';E={$_.Guest.ToolsStatus}},
        @{N='ToolsVersionStatus2';E={$_.Guest.ToolsVersionStatus2}},
        @{N='ToolsRunningStatus';E={$_.Guest.ToolsRunningStatus}},
everything returns other than uuid and powerstate because those values are in $vms arraya and not in Get-View

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [common `-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable) in combination with a [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) call:

```bash
foreach ($vc in $vclist) {
    Connect-Viserver $vc -Credentiol (get-Credentiol)
    $vms = Get-VM

    $vmsView = 
      # Note the use of Write-Output and -PipelineVariable vm,
      # which stores each element of $vms in self-chosen variable $vm
      # as it is being output to the pipeline, so that later script blocks
      # can reference it.
      Write-Output $vms -PipelineVariable vm | 
      Get-View | 
      Select-Object @{N = 'VmId'; E = { $vm.VMId } },
                    @{N = 'HWVersion'; E = { $_.Guest.HwVersion } }
}
```

Note that the self-chosen target variable -`$vm` in this case - must be passed
*without* `$` to `-PipelineVariable`, i.e. as `-PipelineVariable vm`

As [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) points out, you can simplify your command by using `Get-VM` *directly* in your pipeline, by replacing `Write-Output $vms -PipelineVariable vm` with `Get-VM -PipelineVariable vm`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use `ForEach-Object` to wrap the calls to `Get-View`:

```
$vmsView = $vms |ForEach-Object {
    $vm = $_
    $vm |Get-View | Select-Object @{N = 'HWVersion'; E = { $_.Guest.HwVersion } },@{N='PowerState';E={$vm.PowerState}}
}
```